# Little green "+" button no longer displayed in the Django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

models.py

```
class Lab(Model):
    professor = ForeignKey('Author')
```

admin.py

```
class LabAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = LabForm

register(Lab, LabAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
class LabForm(ModelForm):
    professor = ModelChoiceField(Author.objects.order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Lab
```

---

**Situation:** I had to use a custom form for the admin because the entries of the professor drop-down list were not alphabetically ordered.

**Problem:** Because of this, there is no longer the little green "+" button after the drop-down list, in order to directly add (in a pop-up) a professor while beeing in the Lab adding admin form. Django normally automatically creates the green button and the form, but since I use a custom form it has disappeared.

**Request:** I want back this little green "+" button after the professor drop-down list.

Comment: Is the Author model enabled in your admin.py?

Comment: Yes, it is. Before I used a custom form it worked fine, but since I made my own the "+" button doesn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't really answer why the add button is missing but anyway: you don't need a custom form to override the author formfield's queryset, you just have to override `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey`

```
class LabAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # form = LabForm

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "professor":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Author.objects.order_by("name")
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs
            )
```

or you could just make "name" the default ordering for `Author`.